# How to use Custom Map image in myview?

Tags: android

used image as like map , user can zoom in/out this image.geting x and y postion and set small 
image overlay in this main map image. please anyone suggest which steps follow for this ?

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer image over actual map view??

Comment: yes ..i am not used google map in my application. i am required only specified area image in myview. user can see only this area image and sub points on specified x and y position. so how can this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved my problem using canvas ondraw() method and draw image on specified x and y position.